# How to replace NaN value with median with MICE?

Tags: r, r-mice

I tried to replace NA value with median of a column by the following code

```
imputed_data <- mice(data, method="median")
```

I found that there's no method to replace NA value with median with MICE package

```
Error in get(fn): object 'mice.impute.median' not found
```

Is there any way to replace NA value with median using MICE?

Comment: would using base package also help or you only want a solution using MICE?

Comment: There are several options to place NAs: `replace(data$var, is.na(data$var), median(data$var, na.rm=T))`. Look at `data.table::nafill` and `zoo::na.fill`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to replace NA by the median, you don‘t need to overcomplicate things with `mice`. You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
imputed_data <- data %>%
  mutate(column = if_else(is.na(column), median(column, na.rm = TRUE), column))
```

where 'column' is the name of the column you want to recode.